# Gallery limit problem on a flash template

Tags: flash, templates, gallery

I'm working in another template, and i have this problem with the gallery.

I need more than the 10 pictures on that template, but i really don't know how to add another picture to the website.

the thing is the gallery is the website (more or less) and i can't find the way to add another picture to the gallery.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Images and text in your template are embedded into the FLA.  You will have to seek the layers and frames where everything happens, then copy what's there.  Since this is a one-time problem and very localized to your particular use-case, I doubt anyone from SO will look into it deeply enough to solve your problem for you - sorry.

Comment: really? :(. But maybe putting me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

open xlm document with name gallery.
you are going to see the sequence of the code.
i think that the only way is to continue putting the code and the images number.
i give u the example.
- forChanging/galleryImages/8.jpg IMAGE TITLE 8  - forChanging/galleryImages/9.jpg IMAGE TITLE 9  - forChanging/galleryImages/10.jpg IMAGE TITLE 10

now you have to continue by adding new linew of code and changing the numbers IMAGE TITLE 11, IMAGE TITLE 12 ecc...
i hope that i help you